# How to add space between two components in StackView?

Tags: swift2, uistackview

In a brand new project, I've added a button as the top component and text field below it.  I have them set to fill width horizontally.  I then group them into a stackview. At this point, the stackview blows everything out.

I set the stackview constraints to 0 on all four sides.  The button takes up all the space.  I set a constraint for height of 30 on both objects.  Things look normal again.

The problem is that I can't get any vertical space between the button and textfield.  How is that done when you're in a stackview?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can enter the `Spacing` for the stack view members in the attribute inspector of the stack view.

[image]

Comment: Thanks.  How did you create the animated gif?

Comment: Your welcome. I'm using a neat app called LICEcap. The v1.25 for OS X works fine on El Capitan. http://www.cockos.com/licecap/